# Parsing Data From HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using the data.js plugin for highcharts. Using their basic [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/) I have created my own [test](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/xYFBV/) version using our .NET generated table. The documentation on this is very sparse (essentially it is what is in data.src.js). I am getting errors that it is sending in data values as strings (HC error #14). I am not entirely sure how to modify the code to make it work with my simple table.

Here is my js code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: document.getElementById('ctl00_Main_content_ucDashboard_ctl00_ctl11_ctl02_lstData_tblData')
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        }
    });
});
```

Additional info:
It appears that the issue is that my table cells contain `span` tags encapsulating the values. I have no control over those tags and are there for presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<span>` tags within the table are the problem. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: $('#ctl00_Main_content_ucDashboard_ctl00_ctl11_ctl02_lstData_tblData').clone(true).find('span').replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; }).end()[0]
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    });
});
```

(you could also simply remove the span tags from where ever they are coming from)

http://jsfiddle.net/5Gjyy/

Comment: Okay, interestingly it is also because I have values like `165,697`. The data.js code does not like that. So I modified your code a bit: `table: $('#ctl00_Main_content_ucDashboard_ctl00_ctl11_ctl02_lstData_tblData').clone(true).find('span').replaceWith(function () {
                return this.innerHTML.replace(',','');
            }).end()[0]`

Comment: Nice how you took up my solution and extended it ;) Maybe it comes from the fact that the thousands-separator can be mistaken for a decimal pointer and therefore they take a conservative approach.

Comment: Indeed. Now to do the same for any other special characters such as `$` for our wage tables.